# vector in C++ can only read the last element

Tags: c++

I add several element to the vector, but when I visit them, they are all the one which is added at last. I can't understand.

here is my code:

```
while(true){
    cin>>shape;
    if(shape=='X') break;
    if(shape=='C'){
        cin>>x>>y>>r;
        Circle c(x,y,r);
        shapes[sum] = &c;
        //cout<<shapes[sum]->getArea()<<endl;
        sum++;
    }else if(shape=='R'){
        cin>>x1>>y1>>x2>>y2;
        Rectangle rec(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        shapes[sum] = &rec;
        //cout<<shapes[sum]->getArea()<<endl;
        sum++;
    } else if(shape=='T'){
        cin>>x1>>y1>>x2>>y2>>x3>>y3;
        Triangle tr(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);
        shapes[sum] = &tr;
        //cout<<shapes[sum]->getArea()<<endl;
        sum++;
    }
}
for(int j=0; j<sum; j++){
    showArea(shapes[j]);
}
```

I found that at last, all the element in the vector is same, they are the element which is added at last.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please if you want a concise answer and not guesswork.

Comment: I suspect that your vector stores pointer. And you store pointer of local variable => UB

Comment: Furthermore, unless the vector have its size set from the beginning, `shapes[sum]` is probably out of bounds. Another case of undefined behavior.

Comment: How do you know how large your shape vector should be? Maybe the user just continuouswith adding elements. So it would be better to use shapes.push_back(). Furthermore, you are adding pointers (do to `&') and not a copy of the object itself.

Comment: Judging by the limited code presented and the class names, pretty sure pointer storage is intentional (it looks to be a classic polymorphism lesson). The method, however, is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your vector stores pointer. And you store inside it pointer of local variables:

```
} else if(shape=='T'){
    cin>>x1>>y1>>x2>>y2>>x3>>y3;
    Triangle tr(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3); // <= Create local variable, automatic allocation
    shapes[sum] = &tr; // <= store its address
    //cout<<shapes[sum]->getArea()<<endl;
    sum++;
} // <= automatic dealocation of tr, ie tr doesn't exist anymore
  // shapes[sum - 1] stores address of no more existing variable => Undefined behavior
```

you should do:

```
} else if(shape=='T'){
    cin>>x1>>y1>>x2>>y2>>x3>>y3;
    Triangle *tr = new Triangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3); // manual allocation
    shapes.push_back(tr);
    //cout<<shapes[sum]->getArea()<<endl;
    sum++;
}
```

**BUT** you *have to* deallocate with `delete` when you don't need anymore objects in vector

---

`sum` isn't necessary: you have to use `push_back` to avoid Undefined Behavior, and after, you can use `shapes.size()` to retrieve size of vector.

Indeed, accessing to an element of vector which is out of bound (*ie* when you do `vector[n]`, `n` is equal or greater than `vector.size()`) is undefined behavior.

---

Modern way of doing this: use of `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`

Comment: but this example works:#include<iostream>  
#include<vector>  
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;  
int main()  
{  
    vector<int*> k;  
    int *p = new int[15];  
    for (int j = 0; j<15; j++)  
    {  
        p[j] = j;  
        k.push_back(&p[j]);  
    }  
    for (int i = 0; i < 15;i++)  
    {  
        cout << *k[i]<< " ";  
    }                          
    delete[]p;  
    system("pause");  
    return 0;  
}

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have helped me a lot.